# How to refresh the jquery treegrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treegrid

I am using jquery treegrid in my application.And, I have added some custom classes to its rows after page load.These classes are getting added properly to the rows, but it is not showing the collapsing/expanding functionality anymore.I think I need to refresh the grid after adding the new classes.I tried $('.tree').reload();But it is not working.Please help me in solving this.

Adding the code,

```
$('.tree').treegrid({
                 expanderExpandedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus',
                 expanderCollapsedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
             });
             $(".tree").css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                "left": "14%",
                "top": "208%"});
```

### html

```
<table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-1">
        <td>Root node</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2">
        <td>Node 1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-3">
        <td>Node 1-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-4">
        <td>Node 1-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-6">
        <td>Node 1-2-1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-5">
        <td>Node 1-3</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### After page load, adding custom classes to the table rows to create  parent child relations

```
for(i=0;i<nodelist.length;i++){
                var parent=nodeparent[i];
                var child=nodelist[i];
                var parentrow=$(".tree").find('tr td:contains("'+parent+'")');
                var parentrowelement=parentrow.closest("tr");
                var parentrowclass=parentrowelement.attr("class");
                var parentrowclassToString=parentrowclass.toString();
                var parentRowId=parentrowclassToString.substring(8,10);
                var parentrow=$(".tree").find('tr td:contains("'+child+'")');
                var parentrowelement=parentrow.closest("tr");
                parentrowelement.addClass("treegrid-parent"+parentRowId);
                }
```

Here nodelist and nodeparent are arrays that stores the data displayed in each row.The latter is the parent data of the former.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in your question or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tree').treegrid({
    expanderExpandedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus',
    expanderCollapsedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus'
});
```

Try to initialise your treegrid once again like above with your specs.